# SEO for dynamic website powered by JavaScript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, seo

I had read that SEO is applicable for static website, which holding the information in the initial page itself. Is it possible to get search engines to index the dynamically added information?

I used AJAX for loading information. In this situation how can I optimize a site for search engines?

Comment: I have an answer on Webmasters that addresses the way to do this in 2022: [Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/140252/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make all your content accessible without javascript (ie. ajax). Otherwise the search engine spiders cannot index your content.

Comment: It's incorrect, you can make ajax crawlable http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html

Comment: Googlebot now renders Javascript and Google has deprecated the crawlable AJAX scheme that uses hash bang (`#!`) URLs.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to use javascript and Ajax is to first code your pages and delivery content without javascript. All content should show in a logically organized manner. Once this is done you can use JS/Ajax to provide superior usability to the visitors who have JS enabled.

That will benefit all your users, javascript enabled and disabled, and the search engines.

Answer (score 0):

As long as each page has a unique URL (either by url rewriting or by query string parameters) and uses that to drive the content being displayed SEO will work.

I've done this a number of times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your content is accessible to clients without JavaScript. You may have JavaScript on your pages that changes the content based on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about this, but IMHO, using semantic markups and submitting sitemap to Google helps a lot.

Comment: XML sitemaps are almost useless for SEO.  They can get Googlebot to come crawl URLs, but Google doesn't usually index URLs that it can only find through the sitemap.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: Semantic markup has little to no effect on indexing and rankings.  Google cares about content, not markup.  At best using structured data in your pages can enable some rich snippets in the search results. Google has said there is no general ranking boost for using structured data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a website that has AJAX and is search engine compatible but it must be created such that the same information can be accessed without AJAX through the same URL. Search engine cannot execute Javascript and as such any content only available through Javascript will be inaccessible to the search engine.

You need to either provide this content within the `<noscript>` tag or within the page by default and have the Javascript hide it for your AJAX version.

You cannot deliver a different page to a search engine such as Google as they will generally crawl a page both as their bot but also masking as a user by sending a user-agent string purporting to be say, Internet Explorer. This is their method for ensuring you're not trying to game the search engines and they're seeing the same content as a regular user.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I have create a sitemap of the site.
For example, in my sitemap I have

```
www.example.com/level_one/level_two/page1.html,
www.example.com/level_one/level_two/page2.html,
...
```

So the crawlers (Google, yahoo, Bing, etc) knows what to look for. But when an user goes to `www.example.com` always use pure AJAX site.
So you need to acces the pages in the sitemap like a static site.

Other way to solve this (more work) is to make page compatible without JavaScript, so if the user can execute JavaScript you rewrite all href to "#" (for example)

Please check: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/give-each-store-a-url/

Answer (score -2):

SEO ultimately is based on have a good site. 
Things that will help you are links from other "good sites", Having descriptive friendly, URLS, page titles and H1 headings
submitting sitemaps to google and using there webmaster tools is a great starting place

Comment: Although what you say is true it's not answering the question at all.

Comment: that's because the question has been edited and no longer reflects what i answered